# Enterprise Time Tracking Software

Tags: time-management, information-management, reporting, business-intelligence

I am looking for an enterprise time tracking/timesheet software. I want one that has all the features of Replicon TimeAttend and TimeBill. It must have

- bi-weekly approval processes (as in, timesheets are due after two weeks and then are sent to the respective supervisor for review and approval)
- vacation and leave requests built in
- a high degree of report customization (user defined fields for example)

Lastly, I want it to have several attributes that can be assigned for tracked time. By this I mean that time should be logged through several levels of hierarchy. For example: *Classification > Billable/non-billable > Project Code > Activity Code.*

Edit:

- Pricing is flexible, the lower the cost the better, but I'm looking for features above all
- The software could be cloud based (accessed through browser), or server based
- If it is not a web application then it must run on windows. I doubt there is going to be many options that are not web app's, given the nature of the software (timesheet software should be easily accessed by employees from anywhere, regardless of the device and OS they are running)
- To be clear, the features in TimeBill and TimeAttend are that you can store all user information (including user defined fields), all project and client information that is relevant to reporting and payroll. Also, you can of course record your time under various projects and activity codes. You also can create reports that are pretty customizable. For example, in a regular spreadsheet style report you can add custom columns that are customized using some sort of query language (formula's, constants, operations, are all similar to the syntax of MS Excel)

All recommendations are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We don't know what features TimeAttend and TimeBill have – so we must assume your explicitly listed requirements are complete. What is definitely missing is: What OS must it run on, and how much are you willing to invest if it comes to paid software?

Comment: @nadnerb, price range...? Under $1k or under $1m?

Answer (score 0):

(*Full disclosure: I'm one of the developers of the product mentioned*)

It sounds like you can use [TimeTell](https://www.timetell.com/), it meets your requirements mentioned here:

- Time bookings can be assigned to (hierarchies of) projects, activities and customers.
  These all have periods to prevent e.g. booking on projects in the past.
  Optionally you can e.g. couple projects to default/fixed customers.
- Timesheet submission and approval works with reminders that you can schedule.
- Vacation and leave requests (also with an approval process).
- Employee registration has contracts, work schedules, authorisation; all hooked into the other functionality.
- Report designer (and many pre-designed reports). This does not have a 'query' language, but you have full access to the data dictionary.
  Data can be exported to Excel from many points (views) in the program.
- There's a Windows version or a more limited online version; optionally your users can use an Android/iOS app.

TimeTell is used in large enterprises, so there are many more features.
You would need to schedule a call to drill down to your required functionality and get a price offer. Pricing is modular and based on the number of end users.